# Magento - Fatal Error in Mediafallback.php - 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, swatches

Two categories on my website mrmobileuk.com are showing the following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php on line 61

These are the categories:

http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/lcds-digitizers-spare-parts.html

http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/lcds-digitizers-spare-parts/spare-parts.html

Rest other categories are fine.

There have been posts on this issue previously too on your site but no recommended solution has been posted in response.

---

@murtaza and rest who have been following this post.

There was no problem with the Mediafallback.php file.

Do not edit the core file.

I created new categories and tried to place the products in these new categories one by one. The error showed up again after moving a certain product which was the main cause. It was a configurable product but it wasn't associated with simple products. So I deleted that product and created again and was all fine after that. Because of that, the whole category was showing an error. I still do not know why that product was causing an error but deleting it solved the issue. So if you are keen to know why, you can investigate on that part.

Comment: Which Magento version are you using exactly ?

Comment: @Rahphael Am using 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

copy

`Magento_Base_DIR/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php`

to

`Magento_Base_DIR/app/code/local/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Mediafallback.php`

and change line number 61 from

```
$optionLabels += $attribute->getOptionLabels();
```

to

```
$optionLabels .= $attribute->getOptionLabels();
```

this is how I solve this error.

**Edit**

```
$optionLabels = $optionLabels + $attribute->getOptionLabels();
```

**Edit2**

```
 $optionLabels = array_merge($optionLabels , $attribute->getOptionLabels());
```

Comment: @Murtaza There is no ConfigurableSwatches folder in Magento_Base_DIR/app/code/local/Mage/ - Do you want me to copy whole folder in to that?

Comment: @sash create one folder and paste that php file and then change the code in local code pool

Comment: @Murtaza I created the folder and edited the file - it worked - but the swatch icons are not showing up now - they are showing an image instead of the colors - http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/protection/tablet-protection/fitted-cases.html

Comment: @sash try edit  line instead of previous

Comment: @Murtaza That brought the swatch icons back but the error is back again too - http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/lcds-digitizers-spare-parts.html

Comment: Have you set attribute option lable ??

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean my setting attribute option label? I have this on line 61 now - $optionLabels = $optionLabels + $attribute->getOptionLabels(); which has swatch icons visible but error still exists

Comment: where is the error now means on which page?

Comment: http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/lcds-digitizers-spare-parts.html

http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/lcds-digitizers-spare-parts/spare-parts.html

Comment: @sash check edit2 and apply that solution

Comment: I replaced the line with Edit2 - Error is gone now but the swatch icons are all mixed up - For example - http://mrmobileuk.com/index.php/protection/tablet-protection/fitted-cases.html - there should be 5 different color options and it is showing 3 random colors and when clicked on them - random colored images are showing up

Comment: ok got it there should be some problem in your `list.phtml` file that is causing this issue

Comment: Could you help me in figuring out the problem in list.phtml please?

Comment: provide me code of `list.phtml` file

Comment: the code is to long to post in this comment. What is the best way to get to you? and is this the right path - /app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product - list.phtml

Comment: @sash add in your question

Comment: code is in excess of 30000, mine is 38857